# Unable to view an image in S3 in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

My goal is to upload a ***jpg*** file to ***s3*** bucket and I've done using **boto3** library.

[image: Uploaded image file]

When I was trying to open that file in s3 bucket using the displayed link I'm facing an error.

**ERROR:**

**This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.**

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>7C702F46589DF223</RequestId>
    <HostId>
       /CbLJfLthWd2n6br7m1fkSy3W71yyKMWavtOxk/8h/afUr3w09cXl5e1eU8lppXSP7AU90jbymE=
     </HostId>
</Error>
```

**Edit1:**
After following answer suggested by **@CaffeinatedCod3r**, I'm getting following error.

[image]

Comment: What i posted was a sample policy. You have to use bucket policy generator link below the text box. It will generate the police. Paste it in the policy box.

Comment: the access credentials used while uploading a files using boto3. are your sure that user is having getObject permission on this bucket's objects?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to view the image in browser.

For that, you need to

1. Open the `S3` object in your `AWS`.
2. Go to properties of the `S3` object.
3. Go to `Metadata` section.
4. There will be a property called `Content-Type`. It's initial value might be `binary/stream`. Change that to the type of image like `image/jpeg`, `image/png` 
   or `application/pdf` (if you are dealing with pdf files) etc.

Now you should be able to view the image or file in the browser tab instead of downloading.

Answer (score 6):

Before you download a file using generated web URL, you need to apply public permissions using  "bucket policy" tool.
In order to apply the bucket policy, perform the following steps:

1. Open S3 management console https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/
2. Choose a bucket, click "Permissions", click "Bucket policy".
3. Apply the policy using AWS policy generator.

You have to apply policy for `GetObject`.
**Note**:This will give download permission to everyone who have got the link.

A sample policy would look like this

```
{
"Id": "PolicyID",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "StmtID",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<YOUR_BUCKET_NAME>",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Edit after @mondyfy answer the policy would be**

```
   {
      "Id": "PolicyID",
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Sid": "StmtID",
          "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<YOUR_BUCKET_NAME>/*",
          "Principal": "*"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Updated question after following your answer

Answer (score 1):

I have also got a similar issue following the answer suggested by @CaffeinatedCod3r, Here I have a slight update on the above answer and it's working, maybe it will be helpful for others:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicRead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<YOUR_BUCKET_NAME>/*"
    }
   ] 
 }
```

Note: In order to view any bucket object in the browser we need to make sure that we have to set Content-Type of media that the browser needs to render as suggested by @Jarvis and object or bucket should have public read access.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement in policy Resource. I will update my answer based on the suggestion.